# In NodeJS, is res.sendStatus(status).send(message) Invalid?

Tags: node.js, express

Whenever I return my HTTP response with : `res.sendStatus(status).send(message)`

I get this error:

```
Exception from a finished function: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

I couldn't understand where I was sending a response twice, but the error stopped when I removed `.send(message)`

So is this not a valid response? I've resorted to logged the messages instead of using `.send()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`status()` sets a HTTP status on the response (as a Javascript object on the server side).

`sendStatus()` sets the status and also sends it to the client which is similar to `res.status(200).send('OK')`

You are trying to send the response twice, thus giving this error.